# I have installed centos 8 recently, I need to install windows replacing centos from my machine. How can I do it should I create a new disk format?

Tags: system-installation

I have installed centos 8 recently, I need to install windows replacing centos from my machine. How can I do it should I create a new disk format? I don't need dual boot as I have less RAM(4GB)

Comment: What has the amount of RAM got to do with wanting a dual-boot machine or not? It makes no difference.

Comment: Probably as at superuser.com instead. This is *not* a UNIX&Linux question actually.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you need to *replace* CentOS with Windows. That of course breaks our hearts ;-). That said: in the storage part of the Windows setup routine, you can remove all existing partitions and opt to use the entire drive for Windows. That will effectively remove CentOS, from the boot loader as well.